# Horizontal line not displayed in html email in Android

Tags: android, html, email

I want to draw a horizontal line to separate data in HTML  for **sending email** in my android application. For this I used

```
       <hr align="left" size="4" width="370" color="maroon" />
```

But the line is not displayed in  email.When execute  here http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro   it works.Why does it happens and How to solve this?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

`Html.fromHtml()` does not support `<hr>`